# How to use Self Join to iterate through the table and get recent data in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, self-join

How to use Self Join to compare through all the datas from table in SQL Server 2008.

I have a table containing following fields.

1. Item_Type
2. Item_Categ
3. Item_No
4. Item_Year
5. Tran_No
6. Stage_Date
7. Stage_Code

First 4 fields together called as **ITEM_CODE** are important, not unique and are used in all other tables for joining and all. And First 5 fields together make a primary key.
stage_code, stage_date and tran_no will be updated each time.

I want the Stored procedure to get the items that has stage_code = 43 at my given time range(in procedure parameters I'll give the date range) and after that it attained the stage_code = 49

```
SELECT IM.type, IM.categ, IM.divn, IM.item_no, 
IM.item_year,IM.tran_no,IM.stage_date,IM.stage_code
FROM item_status IM, item_status IS
WHERE IM.type = IS.type AND IM.categ = IS.categ AND IM.divn = IS.divn
AND IM.item_no = IS.item_no AND IM.item_year = IS.item_year
AND IM.tran_no = IS.tran_no
//Iterating Loop
```

What I want from the table is,

```
ITEM_CODE       Stage_Date       Stage_Code

0/1/12/2002    01/12/2002           43  // Send For Testing
0/1/18/2002    22/12/2002           43  // Send For Testing
0/1/12/2002    01/02/2003           58
0/1/18/2002    22/12/2002           58
0/1/12/2002    01/05/2003           68
0/1/18/2002    22/05/2003           68
0/1/12/2002    01/08/2003           49  // Success
0/1/18/2002    01/09/2003           70  // Failure
```

Now I want to get the list of products that are gone for testing from 'some date' to 'some date' and had "Succeeded".. So In this case, I just want to get the ITEM_CODE as "0/1/12/2002" and not as "0/1/18/2002"

How to make this work done???

Comment: Please post the query that you have written so far. What kind of comparison are you looking for? Please provide some sample input and output.

Comment: I just joined the table using self join... I dont know how to iterate through..

Comment: Hi @ShantanuGupta, I have updated my post, now please look into it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want (...) to get items that have `stage_code = 43` [within a] given time range(...) and [which have later] attained the `stage_code = 49`. (...) I just want to get the `ITEM_CODE` [when it reached `stage_code = 49`, i.e. "successful"]*.

So you want `ITEM_CODE`'s `WHERE stage_code = 49` and "having previously reached `stage_code = 43` within your chosen date rage".

```
SELECT item_code
FROM item_status AS status_success
JOIN item_status AS status_testing
    ON status_testing.item_code = status_success.item_code
    AND status_testing.stage_code = 43
    AND status_testing.stage_date BETWEEN [start_date] AND [end_date]
    AND status_testing.stage_date < status_success.stage_date
WHERE status_success.stage_code = 49;
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know much about SQLServer's SQL syntax, so the above might need some syntactic tweaking. As such, I have no idea how to wrap this inside a stored procedure, but I assume this is trivial.